# Highly abnormal graphic glitch on yosemite / retina: all white backgrounds appear pink

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, graphics, display

Suddenly, all white and transparent image backgrounds appear pink for me (but only on images, not on anything else that's renderered).

For example, the SE searchbar looks like this:

[image: searchbar]

Or the latest email from amazon:

[image: amazon]

Or the tag:

[image: tag]

The problem does only occur on HiDPI resolutions. If i launch Display Menu and switch to a normal resolution, the problem disappears.

This started after i had the decency to run Quartz Debug Tool to read the FPS of the OS X GUI. I clicked "Disable 2D Acceleration", but it froze my system and forced me to reboot.

Something must have gotten messed up. Anyone know how i can remedy this?

I tried a PRAM reset and deleting windowserver plist files. To no avail.

MBP Mid 2014 | 1TB | 2.8 GHz | 16 GB | Intel Iris Pro / NVidia GeForce GT 750M

Answer (score 1):

After a night's sleep and some clear-headed research, i found the solution by running:

```
defaults delete -g CGContextHighlight2xScaledImages
```

... which is a debugging feature that comes with Quartz Debug and which i had set there (and forgotten) by checking the "Color 1x artwork" option.